# APEX Tabular Form automatically refresh

Tags: oracle-apex

How can i automatically refresh a Tabular Form i used this but it didnt work but it works in a classic report. Where `P4_LIST` is the static id of the Tabular Form.

`var refreshId = setInterval(function(){    
        $('#P4_LIST').trigger('apexrefresh');
      }, 2000);`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't select the partial refresh of the Tabular Form. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryied using Dynamic Actions?

You should create a null PL/SQL action which passes P4_LIST item as parameter (in order to alter session value, otherwise the value change is not shown when refreshing report), after that action you must refresh report region. 
Be aware that you must enable "Enable Partial Page refresh" under report properties, this is mandatory!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Tanks for your help. I have already solve the problem and have write there the answer to my problem.

Comment: @macwadu, perhaps you should put you answer in as an answer, and accept it.  Then this question won't appear to be unanswered forever!

Comment: Ok tanks for your help, and sorry for my mistake.